# The source label of LEAST / GREATEST column

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I created a column that shows the earliest timestamp and now I want to create another column that shows the source of that timestamp. This is what I'm using but it doesn't work when one of the timestamp values in the raw data is NULL.

```
SELECT LEAST (timestamp_1, timestamp_2, timestamp_3)
       ,CASE WHEN timestamp_1 is null AND timestamp_2 is null AND timestamp_3 is null THEN NULL
        ELSE CASE WHEN timestamp_1 <= timestamp_2 AND timestamp_1 <= timestamp_3 THEN 'timestamp_1'
                  WHEN timestamp_2 <= timestamp_3 THEN 'timestamp_2'
                  ELSE 'timestamp_3' END
       END timestamp_source

FROM (

    SELECT timestamp_1
           ,timestamp_2
           ,timestamp_3
           ,timestamp_4
    FROM time
)
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
timestamp_1 | timestamp_2 | timestamp_3 | timestamp_4 | MIN_time    | MIN_source

8/5/18 7:00 | 8/5/18 5:00 | NULL        | 8/5/18 9:00 | 8/5/18 5:00 | timestamp_2
9/5/18 9:00 | 8/5/18 7:00 | 8/5/18 3:00 | NULL        | 8/5/18 3:00 | timestamp_3
```

Is there a more straight forward way to achieve the result?

Comment: what database will you run this query on? redshift or postgresql

Comment: redshift, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just painful.  One method that generalizes well uses aggregation.  The performance is not as good as using `CASE` and assumes that the rows have a unique id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, MIN(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as min_ts,
       FIRST_VALUE(which) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts)
FROM ((SELECT id, 'timestamp_1' as which, timestamp_1 as ts
       FROM time
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT id, 'timestamp_2' as which, timestamp_2 as ts
       FROM time
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT id, 'timestamp_3' as which, timestamp_3 as ts
       FROM time
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT id, 'timestamp_4' as which, timestamp_4 as ts
       FROM time
      ) 
     ) t;
```

I'm not a fan of `select distinct` but Redshift doesn't support `first_value()` as an aggregation function.

An alternative is to use some future value to avoid `NULL`:

```
select nullif(least(timestamp_1, timestamp_2, timestamp_3, timestamp_4), '9999-01-01') as least_ts,
       (case when timestamp_1 = least(timestamp_1, timestamp_2, timestamp_3, timestamp_4) then 'timestamp_1'
             when timestamp_2 = least(timestamp_1, timestamp_2, timestamp_3, timestamp_4) then 'timestamp_2'
             when timestamp_3 = least(timestamp_1, timestamp_2, timestamp_3, timestamp_4) then 'timestamp_3'
             else 'timestamp_4'
        end) as which
from (select coalesce(timestamp_1, '9999-01-01') as timestamp_1,
             coalesce(timestamp_2, '9999-01-01') as timestamp_2,
             coalesce(timestamp_3, '9999-01-01') as timestamp_3,
             coalesce(timestamp_4, '9999-01-01') as timestamp_4
      from time
     ) t;
```

Note:  I am assuming that you are using Redshift.  Postgres has simpler ways to do this.

Comment: Yeah, it is painful, doesn't look nice, but I used the second alternative and it works fine. Thanks, Gordon!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff out of curiosity, what would be the simpler ways to do it with PostgreSQL?